# RegEx that extracts content from a string associating it with a pattern 'XX:XX am or pm'

Tags: python, regex

I'm having trouble creating a regex that extracts the phrase associated with a time **XX:XX am or pm**

```py
import re

hh, mm, am_pm = "", "", "" #each hour group element in str format
times_output = [] #list that must accumulate all time in "XX:XX am or pm" format, 'X' is a int value
```

pseudo-regex-patterns (for this type of example input string)

```
"sense" \s* entre las \s* "XX:XX am or pm" \s* y las \s* "XX:XX am or pm"

"XX:XX am or pm" ---> "sense"
"XX:XX am or pm" ---> "sense"
```

```
"sense" a las "XX:XX am or pm"

"XX:XX am or pm" ---> "sense"
```

```
"sense" a las "XX:XX am or pm", a las "XX:XX am or pm" o a las "XX:XX am or pm"

"XX:XX am or pm" ---> "sense"
"XX:XX am or pm" ---> "sense"
"XX:XX am or pm" ---> "sense"
```

```
(...|.|,|;) \s* "sense1" \s* (a las|de las|) \s* "XX:XX am or pm" \s* "sense2"

"XX:XX am or pm" ---> "sense1" + "sense2"
"22:00 pm"       ---> "ya que a las" + "empieza el show"
```

In this case "ya que" and "a las" will be removed

**Regex pattern to extract times from the input sentence no matter what is before or after the times pattern**

**Example 1:**

```py
input_text = "puede ser peligroso salir entre las 18:00 pm y las 20:00 pm hs, por ello yo pienso que seria mejor salir a las 21:00 pm, a las 21:15 pm o a las 21:30 pm ya que a las 22:00 pm empezaria el show"

#sense_pattern = r"(?P()\s.+?)" #THE REGEX THAT I NEED
civil_time_pattern = r'(\d{1,2})[\s|:]*(\d{0,2})\s*(am|pm)?'

#civil_time_unit_list = re.search(civil_time_pattern, input_text_all_in_minus)
civil_time_unit_list = re.findall(civil_time_pattern, input_text_all_in_minus)
```

**Validation hours, mins, and day time (am or pm)**, in this case this is more important **only for the time regex**

```py
try:
    hh = civil_time_unit_list[0][0]
    if (hh == ""): hh = "00"
except IndexError: hh = "00"
try:
    mm = civil_time_unit_list[0][1]
    if (mm == ""): mm = "00"
except IndexError: mm = "00"
try:
    am_pm = civil_time_unit_list[0][2]
    if (am_pm == ""): am_pm = "am"
except IndexError: am_pm = "am"

time_output = (hh + ":" + mm + " " + am_pm).strip()
```

```py
#remove unnecessary connectors in the <<sense>>
sense = sense.replace("entre las", "")
sense = sense.replace("y las", "")
sense = sense.replace("entre las", "")
sense = sense.replace("a las", "")
sense = sense.replace("ya que", "")
```

Then simply create the files with the name of the schedule and inside them write the associated sense

```py
time_output_file = time_output + ".txt"
with open(time_output_file, 'w') as f:
    f.write(sense)
```

In the end the files should look like this (for this example)...

```
18:00 pm.txt ----> 'puede ser peligroso salir'
20:00 pm.txt ----> 'puede ser peligroso salir'
21:00 pm.txt ----> 'por ello yo pienso que seria mejor salir'
21:15 pm.txt ----> 'por ello yo pienso que seria mejor salir'
21:30 pm.txt ----> 'por ello yo pienso que seria mejor salir'
22:00 pm.txt ----> 'empezaria el show'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tricky little problem.  Once you get rid of the connecting phrases, then it's just a matter of "splitting" the string on times.  This seems to do mostly what you want, although it won't handle every strange input variation.  In particular, the sense always comes before the time, so there doesn't seem to be any reason why "empezaria el show" should be used for the final time.

```
import re
sense = "puede ser peligroso salir entre las 18:00 pm y las 20:00 pm hs, por ello yo pienso que seria mejor salir a las 21:00 pm, a las 21:15 pm o a las 21:30 pm ya que a las 22:00 pm empezaria el show"

sense = sense.replace("entre las", "") \
        .replace("y las", "") \
        .replace("o a las","") \
        .replace("a las", "") \
        .replace(",","")

civil_time_pattern = r'(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\s\s*(?:am|pm))'
for m in re.split(civil_time_pattern, sense):
    m = m.strip()
    if m:
        if m[0].isdigit():
            print(f"Write '{content}' to {m}.txt")
        else:
            content = m
```

Output:

```
Write 'puede ser peligroso salir' to 18:00 pm.txt
Write 'puede ser peligroso salir' to 20:00 pm.txt
Write 'hs por ello yo pienso que seria mejor salir' to 21:00 pm.txt
Write 'hs por ello yo pienso que seria mejor salir' to 21:15 pm.txt
Write 'hs por ello yo pienso que seria mejor salir' to 21:30 pm.txt
Write 'ya que' to 22:00 pm.txt
```

Comment: I think that the last condition should probably be stated as a separate regex. The logic to get the **22:00** event, `(...|.|,|;) \s* "sense1" \s* (at|) \s* "XX:XX am or pm" \ s* "sense2"`, where sense1 and sense are any sentences that fall in the middle of that pattern

Comment: Perhaps the problem is my lack of Spanish; I don't know why "o a las" should be treated differently from "que a las".  I also assume this is just an example, and you'll actually need to pull from a wider variety of sentences.

Comment: The issue that just the sentences that remain before are elements that are removed, but there I updated the question so that the logic of that last case is better visualized. 
**"22:00 pm"  ---> "ya que a las" + "empieza el show" ** an then **ya que a las empieza el show**, but only in this particular example **"ya que"** and **"a las"** will be removed with the replace(), but in general regex this is something that should be considered

Comment: Other example of this regex **; alrededor de las 03:15 am suena el reloj de la torre**, the the regex will extract **03:15 am  --->   "; alrededor de las suena el reloj de la torre"**

Comment: You're talking about doing language processing.  The computer would have to understand Spanish to know whether it was the text before the time or the text after the time, right?  That's FAR more advanced than a regular expression can handle.

Comment: yes I know, even with what it has helped me it is already a great help, anyway I don't know if you can think of a regular expression for that last pattern?